# How do you call an AppleScript process from AIR?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, applescript

How do you call an AppleScript process from an AIR native process?

Background:
I've created a script.scpt file and placed it in the root src directory of project.

I'm getting this error with what I have:

```
Error: Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. 'launch path not accessible'
```

What I have:

```
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("MyScript.scpt");
var processArgs:Vector.<String>;

nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
nativeProcessStartupInfo.workingDirectory = File.applicationDirectory;

processArgs = new Vector.<String>();
processArgs[0] = "foo";

nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

process = new NativeProcess();
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

**Solved**
For it to work I needed the absolute path to "osascript" which is the command that runs scripts. In this case that command can be found in (along with a ton of other goodies)
Macintosh HardDrive > usr > bin > osascript

Note: The "usr" directory is hidden. The path is "/usr/bin/osascript"

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("/usr/bin/osascript");
```

After that I passed the script file name as an argument. It also needs the working directory to be set to the directory of the script otherwise you get:

```
  ERROR - osascript: script.scpt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I don't know the first thing about Apple, but it seems to me that "MyScript.scpt" is not the executable itself (it's just a script file, no compiled code). So I suppose its path should be given as an argument to whatever application runs these Apple scripts. That makes this more of an 'Apple' question, so perhaps you should tag it as such.

Comment: Added. In a few places online I've seen this comment, "Set osascript as the nativeProcess executable" but no code was given. It seems that osascript will take a scpt script as an argument. In all the examples a file is created to point to the source as the executable but I can't find that file hence this post.

Comment: It would seem that this 'osascript' is on the OS' classpath, hence I would suspect you just have to do `nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = "osascript";` and then `processArgs[0] = "\path\to\MyScript.scpt";`.

Comment: My guess would be that your script is not located in the correct directory. File.applicationDirectory most likely points to bin-debug, so your file should be there too, not in the project src.

Comment: Thanks guys. It's solved. The executable needs to be set to the file that contains a valid full path to the command irregardless that it's in the OS class path which is probably obvious to Apple developers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer added to the original post.